# Can't figure it out how to resolve javax.persistence.PersistenceException

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, persistence.xml

We are trying to build a JSF application with JPA. For now, we want to make the login feature, but when we run the application on our glassfish server, there is the exception:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named siteMami

We think the problem is somewhere from persistence.xml, maybe at the provider, please help us. Thanks!   Here is the directory structure:

[image: Here is the directory structure]

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="siteMami" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>model.Admin</class>
        <class>model.User</class>
        <class>model.Client</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/siteMami" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

User.java:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "useri")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User implements Serializable
{
    @Transient
    private static long serialVersionUID    = 6837935606727700935L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idUseri")
    private long        id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String      username;
    private String      password;

    /**
     * @param id
     * @param userName
     * @param password
     */
    public User(long id, String username, String password)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userName
     */
    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String userName)
    {
        this.username = userName;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

UserManager.java:

```
package dao;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import model.User;

public class UserManager
{
    private EntityManagerFactory    factory;

    public UserManager()
    {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("siteMami");
    }

    public User getUser(String username, String password)
    {
        EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();

        entityTransaction.begin();

        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.username = '" + username + "' and User.password = '" + password + "'");

        entityTransaction.commit();

        return (User) q.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: How to resolve this problem in Android Studio/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just popped out on the screenshot somehow: Your file is named
"persitence.xml" instead of
"persistence.xml".

Comment: Yes.  The bootstrap will be looking for 'persistence.xml'.  Try renaming the file if you didn't spot that already.

Comment: I changed it, but unfortunately the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

After i changed the persistence.xml file name, i made a copy of META-INF in src and now it works. We have another exception for now, but we'll see. Thank you for your answer.